# Why won't USB Mount to Desktop?

Tags: macos

I have a Mac. I plugged in a USB stick and I realized that I couldn't find the USB in my Desktop folder through the command-line. Turns out USB is mounted to ~/Volumes.

If there's an USB icon on the Desktop, why can't I see it in the terminal? Also since they put a USB icon on Desktop, why not mount the USB to Desktop?

Comment: You'll have noticed whilst in /Volumes, that that's where all the drives really are. The Finder icons are merely a user convenience.

Comment: Is there a question how to configure things or are you just looking for discussion about design decisions?

Comment: @bmike I guess a discussion about design decisions. I was curious about mounting. I'm reading the answers and I don't get why make it as a Finder option. Is it bad to mount to the Desktop?

Answer (score 1):

The usb icon you see in your 'desktop' is a finder's option, it has nothing to do with your actual desktop directory.

You can link the usb to your desktop directory :

```
ln -s /Volumes/"usb" ~/Desktop/"usb"
```

this way you'll have the usb folder on your finder's desktop and you desktop directory

Answer (score 0):

Click on the Finder icon on the dock, then on the Finder text at the apple logo, click preferences, and then you can see show these items in desktopm Check them (sorry for inprecision. I am not on mac now). This views it on the Desktop as a shortcut. I don't think it is feasible to mount a Volume to the Desktop.